# Regular Expressions: Determining if a String is either a number or variable

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am trying to combine two `Regular Expression` patterns to determine if a String is either a double value or a variable. My restrictions are as follows:

The variable can only begin with an _ or alphabetical letter (A-Z, ignoring case), but it can be followed by zero or more _s, letters, or digits.

Here's what I have so far, but I can't get it to work properly.

```
String varPattern = @"[a-zA-Z_](?: [a-zA-Z_]|\d)*";
String doublePattern = @"(?: \d+\.\d* | \d*\.\d+ | \d+ ) (?: [eE][\+-]?\d+)?";

String pattern = String.Format("({0}) | ({1})",
                             varPattern, doublePattern);
Regex.IsMatch(word, varPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

It seems that it is capturing both Regular Expression patterns, but I need it to be either/or.

For example, _A2 2 is valid using the code above, but _A2 is invalid.

Some examples of valid variables are as follows:

_X6   , _ , A , Z_2_A

And some examples of invalid variables are as follows:

2_X6 , $2 ,  T_2$

I guess I just need clarification on the pattern format for the Regular Expression. The format is unclear to me.

Comment: Is the text formatted exactly as in your post?  Is it comma separated?  Or is there another delimiter between `words`?

Comment: Sorry, the commas are not part of the input. They were just used to separate the patterns in my example above.

Comment: Can you give an example of how the original text is formatted?

Comment: The user will input something that begins with an _ or a letter and it can be followed by zero or more letters, underscores, or letters. That is the original text formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, the literal whitespace you've put in your regular expressions is *part* of the regular expression. You won't get a match unless that same whitespace is in the text being scanned by the regular expression. If you want to use whitespace to make your regex, you'll need to specify `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`, after that, if you want to match any whitespace, you'll have to do so explicitly, either by specifying `\s`, `\x20`, etc.

It should be noted that if you do specify `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`, you can use Perl-style comments (`#` to end of line) to document your regular expression (as I've done below). For complex regular expressions, someone 5 years from now — who might be you! — will thank you for the kindness.

Your [presumably intended] patterns are also, I think, more complex than they need be. A regular expression to match the identifier rule you've specified is this:

```
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

Broken out into its constituent parts:

```
[a-zA-Z_]     # match an upper- or lower-case letter or an underscore, followed by
[a-zA-Z0-9_]* # zero or more occurences of an upper- or lower-case letter, decimal digit or underscore
```

A regular expression to match the conventional style of a numeric/floating-point literal is this:

```
([+-]?[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?
```

Broken out into its constituent parts:

```
(        # a mandatory group that is the integer portion of the value, consisting of
  [+-]?  # - an optional plus- or minus-sign, followed by
  [0-9]+ # - one or more decimal digits
)        # followed by
(        # an optional group that is the fractional portion of the value, consisting of
  \.     # - a decimal point, followed by
  [0-9]+ # - one or more decimal digits
)?       # followed by,
(        # an optional group, that is the exponent portion of the value, consisting of
  [Ee]   # - The upper- or lower-case letter 'E' indicating the start of the exponent, followed by
  [+-]?  # - an optional plus- or minus-sign, followed by
  [0-9]+ # - one or more decimal digits.
)?       # Easy!
```

> **Note:** *Some grammars differ as to whether the sign of the value is a unary operator or part
>   of the value and whether or not a leading `+` sign is allowed. Grammars also vary as to whether
>   something like `123245.` is valid (e.g., is a decimal point with no fractional digits valid?)*

To combine these two regular expression,

- First, group each of them with parentheses (you might want to name the containing groups, as I've done):

  ```
  (?<identifier>[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)
  (?<number>[+-]?[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?
  ```
- Next, combine with the alternation operation, `|`:

  ```
  (?<identifier>[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|(?<number>[+-]?[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?
  ```
- Finally, enclose the whole shebang in an @"..." literal and you should be good to go.

That's about  all there is to it.

Comment: That information is extremely helpful, but the issue still remains... What if a character is in between that isn't valid. For instance, A_2_$ is valid based on that regular expression. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: How is `A_2_$` valid according to that regular expression? **Part** of it is valid: The regular expression will match everything up to, but not including the `$`. You can use metacharacters like `^` or `$` to anchor the match. If you are matching input from a text field control where the value of the control must match the pattern, anchor the regular expression to the beginning and end of the string. For instance, `^foo$` matches **only** the string `foo`: it will not match `foo$`, `foobar`, `3foo`, etc. That approach doesn't work, of course, if you're searching a corpus of text.

Comment: This post really helped me figure my way around this problem. I found the solution, and it followed very close to the solution you posted. There were differences, but this got me started. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Spaces are not ignored in regular expressions by default, so for each space in your current expressions it is looking for a space in that string.  Add the `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` flag or remove the spaces from your expressions.

You will also want to add some beginning and end of string anchors (`^` and `$` respectively) so you do not match just part of a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid having spaces in your regular expressions unless you explicitly set IgnorePatterWhiteSpace. To make sure you get only matches on complete words you should include the beginning of line (^) and end of line ($) characters. I would also suggest you build the entire expression pattern instead of using `String.Format("({0}) | ({1})", ...)` as you have here.

The below should work given your examples:

```
string pattern = @"(?:^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_\d]*)|(?:^\d+(?:\.\d+){0,1}(?:[Ee][\+-]\d+){0,1}$)";
```

Comment: The only problem with that pattern is that it doesn't limit other characters beyond the first character. For example, _A_$ is valid if that pattern is used.